# Countvectoriser fitting on whole data or just train data

Tags: python, machine-learning

my data contains sequence of letters for my classification problem. I can turn these sequences to numeric data using kmer (3 letter words are formed), join them and using countvectoriser (how many times the word appears in the sequence instance), I get the matrix of numbers.

I do split the data using `train_test_split` function.

As we know at the training time, there should not be any information of the test data. If the countvectoriser is fitted on the whole data the unique words from the test would also be known.

So am I correct in saying, countvectoriser needs to b fitted on the train data (unique words only from train data) and using this cv, transform the train and test data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right you don't want to leak any information from the test data to the train data so "countvectoriser needs to b fitted on the train data (unique words only from train data) and using this cv, transform the train and test data" is the right practice.